# GitPython: merge remote and local branch to check if there are merge conflicts

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to use GitPython to merge a local branch with its remote and detect if any merge conflicts have occurred. Whats the simplest way to do this? I've been read the gitPython docs and exploring the `merge_tree` method on the index - it seems rather complicated. Anyone know of a simpler way?